# Looking for LED tube bulb that can also dim to replace fluorescent lights

Tags: lighting, fluorescent

I want to replace my fluorescent tube lights with LED versions.  I see that some work with existing ballasts and others require the ballast to be removed.  I am fine with either, but I would like them to be dimmable.

I know product recommendations are "off topic", but I would certainly appreciate any recommendations.  In lieu of that, maybe someone can provide a "focused" resource where I can learn about the different options available?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is replacing the fixture an option?

Comment: The choice is yours, leave the ballast and do not use it, remove the ballast, what is easier for you. Having a ballast is just another device that can go bad.

Comment: "I know this question is off-topic, but I'm going to acknowledge it and ask anyway." :/

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Replacing the fixture is an option.

Comment: Then I would seriously consider doing that. That's what I did with my kitchen several years ago (not dimmed, but might be dimmable - I don't know) and another room (with a dimmer). (And actually a couple of fixtures in the basement too, forgot about those.) The whole "fluorescent tube" ecosystem is based on incremental improvements over the years (more efficient ballasts, better color lighting) but not major changes for 60+ years. Now we have those changes with LEDs - change everything.

Comment: Google "led fluorescent tube replacement dimmable" and see what you like...

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with what dimming technology *you already have*.

### Commercial 0-10V dimming

Currently, you probably have commercial 0-10V dimming, as most of the dimming fluorescent ballasts work with that.

It will not be possible to convert your existing fixtures to LED.  You will need to replace the fixtures outright.  Make a point to identify fixtures which are 0-10V dimmable.

### Triac dimming

This is not usable with existing fluorescents, so I gather you are retrofitting this *now*.  If a novice saunters down to Home Depot and grabs any random "dimmer switch" they will have themselves a triac dimmer.

For this you will need to shop carefully to identify **direct-wire/ballast-bypass** LED replacement "tubes" which accept triac dimming.  Then, you re-wire the fixture so the ballast is entirely bypassed and supply hot/neutral go straight to the tube ends.  I strongly recommend "double-ended" replacement "tubes" as the single-ended wiring is **scary**.

Comment: Question is not 100% clear, but my take on this is "I have fluorescents. I don't have a dimmer. I'd like to replace with LEDs **and** add a dimmer."

Answer (score 1):

Tube (florescent) lighting has made a lot of progress over the years:  From requiring large ballasts and "starters" (which often go bad), to starterless florescent, to LED.

Current tube type LED "bulbs" come in two varieties:

1. Direct connection like the florescent tube they replaced  or
2. Remove the ballast, do some minimal requiring and use 120volt tubes.

If you choose the latter, the tubes come with stick on label that must be affixed to the fixture indicating the fixture has been converted from using ballasts to simply 120v.   The existing connections (colloquialy referred to a the tombstone connections will remain in use.

Personally, I like the 120v, ballast free tubes because it just simplifys  everything.

You'll need to do some product research for compatibility regarding dimmers and the 120v tubes. But that's sorta off topic here. Still, it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Check with your local box store they may have direct replacements for what you have. If you currently do not have dimming I would consider replacing the fixtures with some that support dimming.

Comment: @Gil The only issue I have with your comment is sometimes, esp. older florescent fixtures are quite decorative.  I rebuilt a beautiful fixture for my mother a few years ago in her 1950's art-deco style home.   I would have been a shame to replace it.